# TDD with Mocks all eggs in a basket?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, mocking

Beginning a project with TDD and debating Mocks, it appears the popular choices of a few years back are hit and miss as far as activeness goes. (Moq, Rhino Mocks)

Once you start using e.g. Rhino Mocks (using DI, DDD, etc.) does it quickly become a case of getting tied to the Library? Once you start and have an app built up with a mocking library it seems like it would be a fairly significant change to try use a different framework.

It looks like the syntax and methodology are quite different (at an initial very brief glance) so it's a little disturbing thinking about committing to a Mock framework especially when both have been pretty stale (.NET 4, last changes 2011, etc.) for a while and only now the Rhino Mocks is being taken over by someone new.

Initially the TDD unit tests will probably be just using the Visual Studio attributes.

*It seems like most of the questions about the frameworks themselves are 2+ years old, kind of like the last changes.*

Comment: Well, I guess it is because the frameworks do not need to change with each release of .NET. They are not using the newer features etc. At the end of the day they are "mocking" items and not a framework / library used in Production code unlike say a IoC library which are often changing. Based on that I guess they don't need lots of churn and stay fairly static. Equally that can be a positive, i.e. not having to refactor your tests all for just updating your mock framework. Just my opinion of courses!

Comment: Why use a mocking framework at all? I find the use of such framework redundant in most cases. In the applications I wrote about 70% to 95% of all services are hidden behind a handful of generic interfaces. This results in a handful of generic mock objects in my test suite that I can reuse.

Comment: @Steven, good for you, mate, but I've been using Moq for the last 6 months or so, and gotta tell you, it helps a lot.

Comment: We've been using RhinoMocks for quite a while and are very happy with it. I think using mocking frameworks and IoC results in much cleaner code and whether you are using Moq or RhinoMocks makes little difference if your code is structured for testability.

Comment: @NedStoyanov I'm afraid I partly disagree. If you're using Moq and your code is definitely not structured/written for unit testability, it's extremely difficult to use Moq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it would be possible to create your own mocking abstraction interface similar to the [Common Service Locator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/) abstraction for dependency injection containers, most people go ahead and create a dependency on a particular mocking library.

As have been noted in the comments, the cases are so rare that you might want to change mocking framework that such an abstraction isn't seen as worth the return on investment.